# Securing returning querystrings from third-party website

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, payment-gateway, 2checkout

So I am implementing a payment system with 2co on my website. I am using their 'Header Redirect' which returns the customer to an ASPX page on my website with a bunch of querystrings after a successful payment.

Anyway, I was wondering. What is the proper way to secure this? What If a customer typed the parameters him/herself such as `Payment.aspx?params-here' and added credits as they wish to their account.

How can I make sure that this is 100% authentic?

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution approach to [parameter tampering](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering) is usually mapping the query parameters to something that cannot be easily manipulated, e.g. by using a one-way hash function to create a digest to send along with the original parameter and limiting the duration during which a particular mapping/digest is valid. If the digest matches the query parameter you know the request has not been tampered with.

E.g. your URL

`Payment.aspx?Amount=100`

could become

`Payment.aspx?Amount=100&Digest=53e5e07397f7f01c2b276af813901c2`

Here's an old but still relevant, detailed article on the topic: [Passing Tamper-Proof QueryString Parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125142425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/083105-1.aspx)

In ASP.NET you can use [`Page.EnableEventValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx) which uses a hidden textbox as part of a form to validate that a request was issued from the form:

> When the EnableEventValidation property is set to true, ASP.NET
>   validates that a control event originated from the user interface that
>   was rendered by that control. A control registers its events during
>   rendering and then validates the events during postback or callback
>   handling. For example, if a list control includes options numbered 1,
>   2, or 3 when the page is rendered, and if a postback request is
>   received specifying option number 4, ASP.NET raises an exception. All
>   event-driven controls in ASP.NET use this feature by default.